Tangent space of a $(d-1)$-sphere
I am trying to verify the following statement:

Let $\mathbb{S}^{d-1} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$. For any $v\in T_o ~ \mathbb{R}^d$ with $o$ being the origin $(0,0,...,0)$ of $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$, $\exists p\in\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ such that $v$ is orthogonal to each element of $T_p ~ \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$.

Here $T_q\mathcal{M}$ means the tangent space of $\mathcal{M}$ at $q\in\mathcal{M}$.
I am unsure whether this statement is correct or not and would like to verify it.
I actually tried to generalize this statement as an extension of the theorem:

The perpendicular at the point of contact to the tangent to a circle passes through the center of the circle. A similar result holds for a $2$-sphere as well.

My attempt towards the proof of my first statement:
$T_p ~ \mathbb{S}^{d-1} = \{u\in\mathbb{R}^d \mid u\cdot p=0\}$
So we need to prove (or disprove) that $\exists p\in\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ such that $p=t v$ for some $t\in\mathbb R$ and $v\in T_o ~ \mathbb{R}^d$.
I suppose that such a choice is always possible, but I am unable to prove that formally. Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

If $v=0$, the result is easy. If $v\ne 0$, how do you get a unit vector parallel to $v$?

I'm not sure, but it seems to me (perhaps without strong logic) that it is possible. My intuition is based on visualizations for $d=2$ and $d=3$.

Forget fancy stuff and go back to the first day of vectors in multivariable calculus or linear algebra. What does unit vector mean?

A vector with norm $=1$.

So what scalar multiple of $v$ gives a vector of norm $1$?

That should be $1/$norm of $v$. But how do I use this information in proving my statement in the question?
